# Multiple breaking points in a scene

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e

So my PCs tortured and killed a vampire in a scene, I of course made them all roll breaking points. What I'm not sure is whether I should have treated the torture and murder separate, and made them roll twice.

Comment: I would say that they should roll one break point prior to engaging in the torture, then another prior to committing murder, since their other option would be to let him go.  If they couldn't free him for some reason, and murder was their only option, then I wouldn't consider it a breakpoint.  I'm just basing this on how I think the story should flow, so I won't put it as the answer unless you find it acceptable.

Comment: Don't "answer not answer" in comments, it will be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a complicated question. The murder automatically counts as a breaking point; the GMC rules update states this a couple of times. However, it gets fuzzy about what else is a breaking point. Review your players answers to their breaking point questions and work with them to figure out if the torture would have incurred a breaking point separate from the murder.

Comment: torture is definitely a breaking point per rules of social maneuvering, and upcoming hurt locker stuff. However this doesn't really answer whether or not it's breaking point per scene or action.